# use vr headset to create camera tracking data?

Tags: camera, vr

I'm wanting to use my VR headset (Oculus Rift S) to make camera data that I can use in blender. since AR apps on iPhone can only get you so far. I was thinking about making a first-person camera walk through a room and read somewhere that you can use VR to do this. if VR has no such ability then are there any addons that can simulate walking as camera data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use "OpenVR Tracker Streaming" which is an addon that can be found [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/openvr-tracker-streaming/1236428). It allows you to use VR tracking from steam VR to control meshes or armatures in Blender.